# how to place all product reviews and show them on a single page in category

Tags: ratings, magento-1.8.1.0

I have done a lot of searching prior to me coming here and basically what i was looking to do was to try and place all my reviews under one page or category. unfortunately I haven't yet succeeded. I currently have magento version 1.8.1.0 and i try putting codes in the local. file but it only messed up my site.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can get all reviews of you system using review collection

```
Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                               ->setDateOrder();
```

It will give you all reviews which are approved.

**More Briefly:**
Create a [custom module](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/)  with block class and create layout file:

in block class put the following code:

```
public function __construct()
    {
            $this->_reviewsCollection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                               ->setDateOrder();

        $this->setCollection($this->_reviewsCollection);
    }
```

Let me know if you want to know more details

Comment: yes please can you elaborate more on where or what do i do with "review collection" code.